# register cas service Rest API

Tags: rest, maven, cas

I am trying to add a new service via the CAS ReST Service. I have a few doubts

1. What should be attributeName and attributeValue ? I have kept it as "skip" and "enabled.+" respectively.
2. I am getting "Request is not authorized" when I give a request to add a service. I thought it could be because of TGT, but I found that TGT is not the issue here. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Those are authorization-related attributes; Meaning the authenticated user must have that attribute/value before the request can be accepted.